# Thyme (Black up curled tipped leaves)

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, hydroponic

I have a thyme cutting that has rooted, probably about two months and the tips of some of the leaves are turning black and curling up.

Any idea what that is? Light, nutrient deficiency or some disease?

Additional info, may be of help, it's in a bottle of water with some nutrient feed inside a window that receives over 10 hours of sun daily in the southern hemisphere, so it's summer with average temperatures upwards of 26 Celsius.

(will update with a pic later in the day)

Comment: If its got roots,it should be potted up - without a photo its hard to be 100% sure, but it sounds like its getting a fungal infection - thyme likes dryish soil conditions and doesn't do well in wet/damp being a mediterranean herb plant (full sun, dryish, relatively poor soil conditions)

Comment: Do you still have the picture you mentioned? Could we help with uploading it?